# Gnome Calendar: how to disable notifications for SOME calendars only

Tags: gnome, notification, evolution, calendar

In Evolution one can choose which calendars should have active notifications. Gnome Calendar seems to be missing this feature. Every morning I get a bunch of notifications for all my calendars which is only annoying.

Is there a way to select only some desired calendars for pushing notifications?